# Estimation of multiple regression model with cross-product terms

Tags: regression, self-study, estimation

I am studying statistics and I stumbled on the following question. If we have the following model: Y = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X3 + b4X1X2 + e with X3=X1-X2, which of the parameters can be estimated and why?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As this seems to be related to statistics study, please add the `self-study` tag and read the [guidelines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for such questions. A reference to the source of the question, ideally with a web link, would help, too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All b's are estimated to construct the well-known linear regression line. Furthermore we obtain an estimate of the uncertainty (which is related to the estimation of e's).

Comment: Note, however, that the value of X3 is completely determined by the values of X1 and X2. In that case, can you actually estimate values of all 4 regression coefficients independently?

Answer (score 4):

The model

$$Y =b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + b_3X_3 + b_4X_1X_2 + e,$$

is under the assumption that

$$X_3=X_1-X_2$$

indistinguishable from the model

$$Y =b_0 + \underbrace{(b_1-a)}_{\gamma_1}X_1 + \underbrace{(b_2+a)}_{\gamma_2}X_2 + \underbrace{(b_3+a)}_{\gamma_3}X_3 + b_4X_1X_2 + e,$$

hence there is an identification problem.

Comment: $Y =b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + b_3X_3 + b_4X_1X_2 + e$ with $X_3=X_1-X_2$ leads to $Y =b_0 + (b_1+b_3)X_1 + (b_2-b_3)X_2 + b_4X_1X_2 + e$ which could be regarded as $Y =c_0 + c_1X_1 + c_2X_2 + c_3X_1X_2 + e$

Comment: What is the point for your comment?

Comment: I don't see why taking $X_3 = X_1 - X_2$ would trouble the analysis, by the so called 'identification problem'. The analysis boils down to the last equation mentioned.

Comment: If you interpret the coefficients as effects on Y of a variable.The effect of for example X3 on Y is not unique. You could have $Y = 2X_1 + X_2 + 2 X_3$ so the effects are $(2,1,2)$ or you could have $Y = X_1 + 2X_2 + 3 X_3$ where the effects are $(1,2,3)$.In the model there is not ONE right answer identified and hence it does not make sense to perform an analysis where the objective is to estimate the one true coefficient vector.Simulate the model and it will suffer from perfect multicollinearity and at least one of the coeficients I have named $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ cannot be estimated

Comment: You say "the analysis boils down to the last equation mentioned". But this is just an equation where you have chosen $a = -b_3$ such that the effect $\gamma_3$ of $X_3$ becomes $0$. But why did you choose that value of $a$?

Comment: I did not choose the value $a$, it was merely the outcome of the simple arithmatics. Nevertheless, I think ' The effect of for example X3 on Y is not unique'  cleared the confusion.

Comment: ok fine - still doing the arithmetic you did is the same as setting $a=-b_3$ if you read the equation in my answer and the point is that you really can choose any value of $a$, hence infinite many coefficient vectors are potential solutions. You could also choose $a=b_1$ such that $X_1$ has 0 effect in the resulting equation. The condition not satisfied is the rank condition $\mathbb E[XX^\top]$ full rank.

Comment: Yes, since you can re-express the assumption $X_3 = X_1- X_2$ ( resulted in $ a = -b_3$ ), and for $X_1 = X_3 + X_2$ ( results in $ a = b_1$ ), and lastly for $X_2 = X_1 - X_3$  ( results in $ a = -b_2$ ). Not necessary true for any value of $a$ right, just for the selected cases one obtains the first model.

Comment: Yes it holds for any $a$ because $X_3 = X_1-X_2$ implies $aX_3 = aX_1-aX_2$. So you just add 0 to the original model where $0 = aX_3 - aX_1 + aX_2$. Offcourse when you add zero the model does not change. Simply way of showing that even with infinite data you would not be able to estimate parameters with OLS estimator due to non-full rank of $\mathbb E[XX^\top]$ - it is a standard condition of OLS, just look it up. You can find it as the no perfect multicollinearity assumption of the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares (half way into the page)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I got it.